# Undefined variable in the while loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Cannot work out why I am getting this error with the following code:
"Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from undefined. (line 201, file "Code")"

```
if (variableDate != storageArray[storageCount][1]) {//if dates are equal.
   Logger.log("line 197 executed " + (storageArray[storageCount][1] != 'End'));
   Logger.log(storageArray[storageCount]);
   while (storageArray[storageCount][1] != 'End') {} <-- Line 201 error
```

The log at line 197 returns true, the second log returns an array.

```
[16-08-09 14:22:58:428 AEST] line 197 executed true
[16-08-09 14:22:58:428 AEST] [42590.0, Mon Aug 08 00:00:00 GMT+10:00 2016, , , , ]
```

If I change storageCount variable to an integer it works fine. I cannot fathom why the storageCount variable works in the logger but is undefined in the while loop.

Comment: It looks like you intentionally created an infinite loop. Is there some other asynchronous event that is supposed to revive the loop by changing the `storageArray`? I would look there.

Comment: I created the infinite loop to get past that point. The loop doesn't execute at all, the error says that storageArray[storageCount] is undefined yet the same thing returns true in the Logger two lines above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that:

```
storageArray[storageCount]
```

is `undefined`.  Thus, it is a `TypeError` to try to access `undefined[1]`.

---

You've also created a likely infinite loop here:

```
while (storageArray[storageCount][1] != 'End') {}
```

so, even if you didn't have the `TypeError`, this would just be an infinite loop since if the condition is ever `!= 'End'`, then it can never change so will loop forever.

Comment: It works with [1]. What I cannot work out is why the same thing is not undefined two lines up.

Comment: @allanquartz - I wonder if the logging is confusing you.  Sometimes, there are problems with logging grabbing an object reference and then using it asynchronously later from when the actual code runs (`console.log()` has that problem in Chrome in some circumstances).  I'd suggest setting a breakpoint in the debugger and just watch it execute and see exactly what is going on. The `TypeError` doesn't lie.   Stepping through it line by line in the debugger doesn't lie. The logging could having a timing issue.  You could also try a `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(storageArray[storageCount]))`.

Comment: It was the infinite loop that sent storageCount beyond the length of the array.